# How to determine a parametrization for the field line of the vector field?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, parametrization

Let $F$ be the vector field given by

$$F (x, y, z) = \left(1 + x^2, −(1 + x^2)y, (1 + x^2)z\right).$$

How can I determine a parametrization for the field line of $F$, through $(0, 1, 1)\,$?

I was trying to solve 3 differential equations. But, for example, for the first one I get

$$x(t)= \tan(t+C(y,z)),$$

where $C(y,z)$ is a function that is constant in $x$, but that did not help me solve anything since I later need to integrate it.

Comment: What is a "field line"?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to solve
$$ \dot{x} = 1 + x^2$$
$$ \dot{y} = -(1+x^2)y$$
$$ \dot{z} = (1+x^2)z$$
The first equation, as you worked out, is separable and may be integrated. But this is a full differential equation for $x = x(t)$ (we're parametrising a field line by $t$), not a partial differential equation. So C is just an arbitrary constant.

You'll probably find it easier to integrate
$$\dot{y} = -\dot{x}y$$
than using the solution for $x$. This gives
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -y$$
which is easily solved.

Comment: I did it in that way and got $(x,y,z)=(\tan(t)+c, \frac{1}{e^{\tan(t)+c}}, e^{\tan(t)+c})$, is it correct?

Comment: It should be $\tan(t+c)$. But these constants need not coincide. But you can solve them separately by solving componentwise equations. Note that there is not a unique parametrization since the parametrization need not start ($t=0$) at the point $(0,1,1)$.